# VBScript wont work on www.meteor.ie

Tags: vbscript, windows-server-2003

The .Focus() function will not work in Windows Server 2003. Is there any thing i can do to make it work?

```
WScript.Sleep 1000 
.getElementByID("quickSearchMsisdn").value = "085729916" 
WScript.Sleep 1000 
.getElementByID("quickSearchMsisdn").value = "0857299167" 
WScript.Sleep 1000 
.getElementByID("quickSearchMsisdn").value = "0857299167"
.getElementByID("quickSearchMsisdn").Focus 
WScript.Sleep 10000
.getElementByID("doSendSMS").click
```

It is to log into my online mobile account and send me an automated text. What ever way the page is designed the number field needs to be clicked into.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using Firefox instead of IE.
This posting seems to have some insight/solution.
http://forums.asp.net/p/1098151/3384669.aspx#3384669