# VBScript .focus function doesn't execute on Windows Server 2003

Tags: vbscript, windows-server-2003

The `.focus` function won't execute on Windows Server 2003 when I run my VBScript, however it works fine up to that point. Does anyone know why this could be?

Here's my script:

```
WScript.Sleep 1000 .getElementByID("quickSearchMsisdn").value = "085729916" 
WScript.Sleep 1000 .getElementByID("quickSearchMsisdn").value = "0857299167" 
WScript.Sleep 1000 .getElementByID("quickSearchMsisdn").value = "0857299167"
                   .getElementByID("quickSearchMsisdn").Focus 
WScript.Sleep 10000 .getElementByID("doSendSMS").click
```

Comment: Could you add some example code?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628679/vbscript-wont-work-on-www-meteor-ie

Comment: WScript.Sleep 1000
    .getElementByID("quickSearchMsisdn").value = "085729916"

    WScript.Sleep 1000
    .getElementByID("quickSearchMsisdn").value = "0857299167"

    WScript.Sleep 1000
    .getElementByID("quickSearchMsisdn").value = "0857299167"
    
     .getElementByID("quickSearchMsisdn").Focus
    

    WScript.Sleep 10000
    .getElementByID("doSendSMS").click

its to log into my online mobile account and send me an automated text. what ever way the page is designed the number field needs to be clicked into

Answer (score 0):

There is not Focus Function in vbscript that I am aware of, Maybe you are describing the focus method of some class? Some code would be very helpful.